# Vue JS - How to add zero before month using new Date

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, vuejs2

I have one function that gives the date, the only problem is that my date is displayed like this on **5/31/2021**, but I want to make it appear on **05/31/2021** here is my code

```
<span>{{ dtFormatter(course.updated_at) }}</span>

dtFormatter(d) {
  var dateObj = new Date(d);
  var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
  var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
  var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
  return day + "." + month + "." + year;
},
```

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-UK').replaceAll('/', '.')`

Comment: @HassanImam gave you a one-liner code to solve your problem, but in your question - you are asking on how to show it with slashes '/', but in your code you are returning with dots '.' - If it should be with slashesh, just use the @Hassan's code, without the `replaceAll` function like so: `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-UK')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to add a leading `0` if needed:

```
('0' + day).slice(-2) + '.' + ('0' + month).slice(-2) + '.' + year;
```

Note: [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#browser_compatibility) doesn't work in IE.

Comment: I didn't downvoted yet, but your variables aren't declared in your answer, so if I copy and paste it, it won't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to add a leading `Zero` if needed:

```
day.padStart(2, '0') + '.' + month.padStart(2, '0') + '.' + year
```

`day` and `month` should be a string btw

Answer (score 1):

I see you already calculated the day.
so you can do this.

`0${day}`.slice(-2)`

this will output 01~09 and 10~31.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@HassanImam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4758494/hassan-imam), you could use a one-liner code:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-UK')
```

otherwise:

```js
const date = new Date()
const m = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')
const d = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')
const y = String(date.getFullYear())

const formatedDate = [m, d, y].join('/')

console.log(formatedDate)
```